# CPU/Processor error rate in calculations

Tags: cpu, intel

Does Intel or AMD publish specifications about the rate at what failures in calculations can be expected on their CPUs? I would suspect it would be very age and temperature dependent, but surely there must be some kind of numbers available?

I'm not interested in manufacturing errors. I'm interested in spontaneous errors due to physical phenomena not related to design error. Whether the error originates in the CPU or some other chip on the system is also of interest (for example a momentary voltage failure to the processor would also result in errors).

I'm curious, but my net searching isn't yielding what I want. I just want to get rough ideas of it I left my program running for X hours how many spontaneous errors I could expect to have.

*I'm not sure if this is the best StackExchange site to ask, perhaps electronics instead?*

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16256/cpu-processor-error-rate-in-calculations/

Answer (score 0):

The number is zero. If you get calculation errors and your CPU's temperature is witin boundaries defined by specification, then you have a defect CPU that must be replaced.

Comment: No manufacturing process is that good. I understand the rate will be extremely low/negligible in normal computing, but that doesn't mean it's actually zero.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y you need to learn about manufacturing then. For each processor speed testing is performed where processor speed is pushed up to the limit where it begins to fail. Then the speed is decreased two steps (to leave certain reserve), and then the processor is marked. So processors are guaranteed to be bug-free. If they are not, they are claimed broken and should be replaced.  And in any case your question is off-topic here.